# How can I add axis ticks for dates not present in my data using base R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a created a plot in base R, in which the x-axis is based on dates (months). In some cases, I have no data for a month, so the tick mark on the x-axis is skipped, but this looks awful. Is there any way to draw a tick in the middle of two other tick points in R?

Here is an example of my plot:

```
month<-c("2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-10-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-01-01", "2011-02-01",
 "2011-03-01", "2011-04-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-09-01",
 "2011-11-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-05-01", "2012-07-01",
 "2012-08-01")
prevalence<-c(10,7.5,5.2,3.5,6.4,2.7,5.8,13.2,4.3,4.7,6.4,4.4,5.2,3.3,1.0,3.1,9.9,33.3,1.0)
df<-data.frame(month, prevalence)
df$month<-as.Date(df$month)

plot(df$month, df$prevalence,lwd = 1.8, ylim=c(0,40),pch=16, bty='n', 
 ylab="Prevalence (%)", xlab="Month",col='black',cex=1,cex.lab=1.0,cex.axis=1.0)

axis(side = 1, at = df$month, labels=F, tck=-0.015)
axis(side=2, at=c(0,10,20,30,40,50), labels=c("", "", "", "", "", ""), tck=-0.015)

lines(df$month, df$prevalence, col='black', lwd=1.8)
```

The graph produced:[image]

I have asked a different question regarding this same graph, I hope it was appropriate to post as two separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your x values are of class `Date`, you may use `seq.Date` to produce a regular sequence of dates, which can be used as `at` values, i.e. the positions at which tick-marks are to be drawn (see examples in `?seq.Date` and `?axis.Date`).

```
at <- seq(from = min(df$month), to = max(df$month), by = "month")
```

Then try a plot with tick-marks only and no `labels`:

```
plot(prevalence ~ month, data = df, type = "b")
axis.Date(side = 1, at = at, labels = FALSE)
```

[image]

Furthermore, `axis.Date` easily allows you to `format` the dates. Here, I suppress plotting of the x axis in the `plot`call, by using the `xaxt` argument. Then, I add the axis with desired `at` positions and `format`, e.g. `%y-%m` (year-without-century dash two-digit-month)

```
plot(prevalence ~ month, data = df, type = "b", xaxt = "n")
axis.Date(side = 1, at = at, format = "%y-%m")
```

[image]

See `?strptime` for other possible specifications of date/time formats.